# Install Linux on a disk partition without rebooting the system

Tags: linux, boot, installation

Is is possible to install a new release of Linux (or any OS) on a disk partition without rebooting the present OS but then reboot to it and make it run "natively".

I understand one can do something like run virtual box to install any OS and then start stop it etc. But how does one run that installed OS natively? i.e. without running virtual box - sort of make it a dual boot system where one chooses the image at boot time (or by setting appropriate configs).

So assume the disk is already partitioned. Running version X on one partition. We want to install version Y on another partition without rebooting X (or system). And then in the next boot have a choice to boot X or Y. Y must be "completely" installed - i.e., no completion of install when Y boots.

One possibility seems to be writing out a raw disk image and setting up the bootloader appropriately? Is there a more higher level user friendly way to do it?

Comment: Is it possible - yes. But why do you need this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you running UEFI or legacy (BIOS) booting?

Comment: It is sort of reinstalling the OS in another partition to boot from it later. It should not interrupt the presently running OS.

Legacy BIOS - though change UEFI is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially speaking it ALWAYS work that way. It merely means that instead of using a live environment of the target distro, you use an existing installation (of potentially a different distro) instead. The main difference is that you won't be using a guided installer but will be configuring stuff manually (for distro such as Arch that's even the official / recommended way). Try to look for "bootstrap" tarball or so of the distro / version you want to install.

And as you mentioned yourself, it's even possible to use a hypervisor to install one *additionally* on your existing drive -- just that the practice could be considered dangerous as it risks the current installation / data on the drive. (It would actually be safer if what you want to install is Windows in this case, believe it or not.) Obviously the reason to adopt this approach would be the guided installer. (I'm not ruling out the possibility of using one with the former approach though. It's just I haven't quite heard of it / don't have the picture in mind.)